# DC/OS on Azure set up VPN

Tags: azure, dcos

I've set up a DC/OS container service on Azure and tried to set up a VPN according to the [Access by Proxy and VPN using DC/OS Tunnel](https://dcos.io/docs/1.8/administration/access-node/tunnel/#docs-article).

I used:

```
sudo dcos tunnel vpn --sport 2200 --user=azureuser
```

I'm getting a ConnectTimeoutError

Any suggestions?

Comment: Without more details concerning your setup it's hard to tell, but can you confirm that you can do `ssh -p2200 azureuser@$MASTERFQDN -L 8000:localhost:80` as described at the bottom of https://dcos.io/docs/1.8/administration/installing/cloud/azure/?

Comment: yes, I can do that...